# How to pass on defined variables in sub to function in VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, function, find, boolean, range

In some cells are variables given, e.g x and y which, if they are true,a function P(w) gets startet. E.g. the x which starts P() means that a value in a cell is being checked whether that value =0 and so on. The Array function "IsInArray" looks whether the found value in the given cell equals "x". If so, it is supposed to jump to the function P() command and checks whether the value in the cell = 0. If so, the function P() is true and the macro starts copying some ranges.

My question is: When the macro gets into the function, the already defined Range("A" & t) with e.g "t=3" is not passed onto the function sub. "t" is basically empty. The aim is that the already defined variable "t" is taken from the sub and not declared again in the function part.

Moreover, I dont understand why I have to "Set ws = Worksheets("R")" it again in function part even though it is in the sub party already?

```
 Sub Examine()

 Dim t As Integer
 Dim Results as Boolean

 Set ws = Worksheets("R")
 Set wt = Worksheets("G")
 Set wi = Worksheets("R")

 t = 2


 Do
       For Each cell In ws.Range("A" & t)
       Set foundValue = wi.Range("A1:A75").Find(cell.Value)
           If Not foundValue Is Nothing Then
              If Not IsError(Application.Match("x", wi.Rows(foundValue.Row).Columns("H").Value,0)) Then
If Results=P() Then
 ws.Range("A" & t).Copy wt.Range("A" & t): wt.Range("B" & t) = "J": wt.Range("C" & t) = "N"
 ELSE:.....
 End If ....
 End If
  Loop Until ws.Range("A" & t) = ""


Function P() 
w = True
Set ws = Worksheets("R")
If ws.Range("B" & t).Value = 0 Then w = False 'The already defined"t" is not taken by the function from the sub.
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is: Results=P(t)

Secondly, you have to declare the variable "t" with Byval in the function: e.g

Function P(Byval t as Long) As Boolean